# Incorrect Decimal Formatting NSNumberFormatter

Tags: ios, nsnumberformatter

I have a textfield that will hold only numbers. I need the numbers to adhere to the to have a maximum of 3 significant figures and a maximum of 2 decimal places. I also need to keep the original value and would only like to change the way the value is displayed. I am temporarily solving the issue by splitting the number up at the decimal point and removing more than 2 decimals but I would love to use NSNumberFormatter and remove that code. Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
NSNumber *customCalculation = @(0.04791234);

NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setUsesSignificantDigits:YES];
[formatter setMaximumSignificantDigits:3];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];

customTextField.text = [formatter stringFromNumber: customCalculation];
```

The output is: 0.0479. Not sure where I am making my mistake.

Comment: What output are you expecting for `0.04791234` as input?

Comment: Expecting the output: `0.04`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0.0479` has 3 significant digits as you've instructed the formatter to display. Significant digits are the digits after the leading zeros.

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
```

That'll give `0.05`. To get `0.04` as the output, you'll need to change the rounding behaviour as well (because `0.04791234` should be `0.05` at 2dp precision).

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter setRoundingMode:NSNumberFormatterRoundDown];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
```

Yields `0.04`.